# Get the data type of a FunctionCall such as scope_identity()

Tags: c#, sql-server-data-tools, dac, scriptdom

If I have an instance of `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.FunctionCall`, how do I get the data type of the value that will be returned by the function?

Comment: doesn't the `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.FunctionCall have a GetType method` [MSDN FunctionCall Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.functioncall.aspx)

Comment: @MethodMan, that returns the .Net type of the `FunctionCall` object itself. I need the data type of the return value of the function that the `FunctionCall` represents.

Comment: I don't think that the ScriptDom can tell you that. However using the Dac strongly typed model, you should be able to query it. Check out ScalarFunction.ReturnType here: https://github.com/Microsoft/DACExtensions/blob/master/DacFxStronglyTypedModel/model.cs